# Get fans count from children pages of Facebook global page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-page

There is a method to retrieve the fans count from a child of global Facebook page for example with the classics API-FB graph?

Because with this new feature that FB has implemented recently (I think november 2012), all the sub-pages have a fans count equals to the global page (then the sum of fans count of all children).

For example, with the following FB page (the page of FB-marketing) and executing this query in the developer API-tester (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer), we can see that this page is a global page and has children. BUT when we open one of the children with opengraph the fans count is equal to the parent "global page".

The FQL-Query of the example:

```
SELECT global_brand_child_page_id FROM page_global_brand_child WHERE parent_page_id=74100576336
```

Anyone has found a solution to retrieve the fans count (or likes for the page) for the children only?

Comment: The counts for the child are in those pages' insights, aren't they?

Comment: I think so, but I am not the owner of the pages. And calling it with opengraph, I get a response with the "likes" (= fans) count of the global page (every child have same number of fans (equal to the sum of all child)).

Comment: Yes, that's intentional and part of how the parent/child thing works - the specific like count for the child pages is only available in insights